# Need help in buying GPU for deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, gpgpu

I am in decision phase for deep learning machine I want to use for my learning.
I want your guide in selecting best value GPU between cloud/on-premise.

PS. Right now I am evaluating performance of various GPUs, cloud GPUs in AWS with Kears [Cifar10_cnn](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py)  example.
Below are **1 EPOCH** results for some of them.

1. Tesla k80 - 22 seconds
2. Tesla v100 - 19s (Quiet slower than expected)
3. Quadro K1100M - 120s (laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this fantastic article answering my question.
It has evaluations of various GPUs, cloud and on-premise.
http://timdettmers.com/2017/04/09/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/

Read this blog if you want to build your own machine: 
http://timdettmers.com/2015/03/09/deep-learning-hardware-guide/